# xamarin forms wp81 status bar background color

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, statusbar

I am working on a xamarin.forms app, in my windows phone 8.1 app the status bar text and background color both come white. I tried all styles but nothing works. Below is my code

```
<x:Class="Sthotraani.WinPhone.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Sthotraani.WinPhone"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CommandBar">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#009688" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F98F1C"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ProgressRing">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F98F1C"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs's `OnLaunched` method, you can add something like the following:

```
var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
statusBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;
statusBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.AntiqueWhite;
```

Comment: I tried that, but no luck :(, even added reference to behaviors sdk

Comment: Where in the method are you adding it? It works for me on an 8.1 simulator so I'm wondering why it wouldn't be for you.

Comment: except this line i kept all "statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;" does this causes it ? I will try to put this also in the evening and update you

Comment: The background opacity needs to be set or the color will otherwise stay/appear black.

Comment: Will try it today Thank you @Paul

Comment: That's the only issue, it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.