# How to change background colour of the Home Indicator on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to change the background color to transparent in all screens of my app.

[image]

I'm referring to the solid white bar with the black line at the bottom of this screen.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194557/how-to-change-home-indicator-background-color-on-iphone-x

Comment: This answer is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199029/8358956

Comment: @Rutger Huijsmans - Answer linked to your question will help you. Remove `align bottom to Safe Area` and add `Bottom Space to super View`