# How to set color for home indicator element?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If background is black, it isn't visible.

[image]

Comment: please consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide reproducable copyable code, because this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform but a "we help you with your provided code "-platform

Comment: @emrcftci I understand this and created this question because I don't know how to google my problem ( what's the name of this element? ) .

Comment: this is a view color which has constrainted to `superView`  and white background color

Comment: @emrcftci This view hasn't been created by me. It is system control element, as I understand. And I didn't know it's name. But thanks for Shivam Parmar , now I know, it is "home indicator".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change home indicator background color on iPhone X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194557/how-to-change-home-indicator-background-color-on-iphone-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home indicator color is determined automatically based on the color of the content below it.

Most of the time, this means you should not worry about its color since it is out of your control, and will always be clearly visible to users.

However, you can place a colored view in the area behind the home indicator to manipulate its color.

reference from :- https://medium.com/@nathangitter/reverse-engineering-the-iphone-x-home-indicator-color-a4c112f84d34