# How to change home indicator color for IOS in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I would like to change the color of this view that appears on the bottom of the new iPhones.

Is it possible with using some libraries or with Flutter SDK usage?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The home indicator color is determined automatically based on the color of the content below it.

Most of the time, this means you should not worry about its color since it is out of your control, and will always be clearly visible to users.

However, you can place a colored view in the area behind the home indicator to manipulate its color.

## Examples

(Please note that these examples were taken on the iOS simulator, and behavior on a real device is different.)

[image: Home indicator with white background]

**Background:** white (`#ffffff`)

**Home Indicator:** black (`#000000`)

---

[image: Home indicator with black background]

**Background:** black (`#000000`)

**Home Indicator:** gray (`#484848`)

---

[image: Home indicator with gray background]

**Background:** gray (`#5f5f5f`)

**Home Indicator:** dark gray (`#282828`)

---

[image: Home indicator with blue background]

**Background:** blue (`#1a98fc`)

**Home Indicator:** very dark gray (`#121212`)

---

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199029/9410194)