# SetUseSafeArea for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779966/939213) we can leave space for the iOS status bar by using `SetUseSafeArea`.

But is there something similar for a Xamarin.iOS app that is *not* a Xamarin.Forms app?

Comment: UIView's SafeAreaInsets is what you are looking for:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets?language=objc

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. I'll check it as soon as my app stops crashing on start :( (It didn't use to do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can refer to **[safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)** from Apple document, then there is [another similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9#:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20new%20safe,the%20overscan%20region%20on%20tvOS.) about navitve iOS how to achieve that, you also can refer to do the same in Xamarin.iOS.

Here is the **Xamarin.iOS** sample code for reference:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    
    //suberView is your subview view in ViewController
    View.Add(suberView);
    suberView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    var safeGuide = View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide;
    suberView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;

    View.LayoutIfNeeded();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native, I think the UIView has something very similar. UseSafeArea or something similar. You should be able to search developer.apple.com for UIView and it should provide something for you to enable.

EDIT: Just noticed SushiHangover's comment. Click on the link Sushi provided and it will show you.