# Мy content disappears in order for a Google ad to appear on startup using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, admob

I have the following problem. When I start the application, my content does not appear, and only the banner of Google Ad Mob appears.
Only the GPS permission message appears but not the content itself.

The code I use :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _restServiceForecast = new RestServiceForecast();

        _ = DisplayHourlyForecastStartUp();

        _ = ButtonClickedGPS();

        co2lbl.Text = "CO2";
        nolbl.Text = "NO";
        no2lbl.Text = "NO2";
        o3lbl.Text = "O3";
        so2lbl.Text = "SO2";
        pm2_5lbl.Text = "PM2_5";
        pm10lbl.Text = "PM10";
        nh3lbl.Text = "NH3";

        frameFinePowders.IsVisible = false;

        AdmobControl admobControl = new AdmobControl()
        {
            AdUnitId = AppConstants.BannerId
        };
        Label adLabel = new Label() { Text = "Ads will be displayed here!" };

        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children = { adLabel, admobControl }
        };

        this.Title = "Admob Page";
    }
```

How do I make the banner appear under a certain frame that I want?

[image: Google Ad Mob]

Comment: Your Label is clearly shown at the top of the screen behind the iPhone notch.  There are many existing questions that explain how to adjust your layout to accommodate the notch.

Comment: Can you give me some example, please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779937/how-to-allow-for-ios-status-bar-and-iphone-x-notch-in-xamarin-forms/47779966