# How make the status bar opaque on Xamarin for app without navigation bar

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.forms, f#

I have a app that only have a form with a web view. When the web view scroll (it have a white background) the content slide behind the status bar, turning it transparent (only the battery indicator is visible. The rest text of the status bar was white and now is not visible).

I need the status bar to be opaque, and the content disappear behind it.

I try setting `Status bar style` to default, opaque style and none work. Neither putting the background color of the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms - Change StatusBar Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color)

Comment: I already make that changes but the effect is the same. The status bar change of color, but become translucent when the content scroll behind...

Comment: I see.  Interesting. I'll have to look into that