# How to change text color status bar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to design the status bar with white color, but the color of text and icon of notification the same color, so how can I change the text color of the status bar?.

The status bar color

**before**:

[image]

**After**:
[image]

Comment: Hi,do you just want it in Android devices?

Comment: Hi Jiang, right now my priority is Android, so yes. iOS may be in the future

Comment: Okey ,  I have seen an answer there ,maybe just can work for IOS.i will post my answer later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okey, @Harry Android is different with IOS.

> right now my priority is Android, so yes. iOS may be in the future

**Android:**

Android 6.0 started, Google officially provided support, configure `android:windowLightStatusBar` in the style attribute
Yes, when set to `true`, when the background color of the statusbar is light, the text color of the statusbar will be grayed out. The same is `true` for `false`.As follow:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
       ...
     <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
```

In xamarin.forms can follow [this link](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) to get success.

Basically you have to use `FormsAppCompatActivity` instead of `FormsApplicationActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.Material.Light`.

If want some page show different style ,can change it in activity's theme.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.SecondActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/customttheme"/>

</application>
```

**IOS:**

(1), add follow key-value to `info.plist` in Project.IOS:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

(2) Not using code:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

(3),Or use code to set text color of status bar, method `FinishedLaunching` in `AppDelegate.cs` set as follow:

```
 app.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```

(4)If want some page change color after launching app ,can [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage) `ViewControllerRenderer` for IOS , in `ViewDidLoad()` method :

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, see this answer: [background status bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39164921/4251242).

According to this link, you need to set values of `BarBackgroundColor` and `BarTextColor` to your specific color like so:

```
...
MainPage = new MainPageUser();

  //Background color
  MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, Color.Black);

  //Title color
  MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Color.White);
...
```

Also:

> But like you probably notice now is that the status bar in iOS on top
>   is also black and that you´ll need to change in the Info.plist file in
>   your ios project and open it (right click and choose "open with") with
>   xml editor and add these lines of code:

according to this comment you need to change your info.plist like this:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: NavigationBar is not phone status bar. Please chech question images...

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms from iOS 12 and Above you simply make this in info.plist:

- Open Info.Plist
- Switch to Source Tab
- Add new Entry
- Type "UIStatusBarStyle" without quote

In the right side you can choose color.

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcD6i.png)
[BarColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWMwf.png)