# Change the color of the top and bottom bar (ControlsBar, StatusBar) in a Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there anyway, even if requires platform specific code behind, to change the color of both the top bar (the one in blue) and the bottom bar (the one in black)?

I wish to add support for light and dark modes, so I would like to be able to change that during runtime.

[image: Android]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color

Comment: Thanks, but what about the bottom black bar? I saw some apps changing the color of that component, so I think that it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is possible** .

**Android:**

Using `Window.SetStatusBarColor` and `Window.SetNavigationBarColor` can do that easily above Android API 21.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Lollipop)
  {
       Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);
       Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);
   }
```

[image]

**IOS:**

In ios, change navigation bar and status bar , can use as bellow:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.YouWantColor;
// Color you want, such as UIColor.Green
```

[image]

After click button, changed dynamically to green color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what about iOS?

Answer (score 1):

**Android**

`Build.VERSION_CODES.Lollipop` is obsolete. Use `Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes`:

```cs
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
  Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange;
  Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange;
}
```