# How to keep top part of the screen from moving using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I would like to keep the top where the time is to be pinned and with a gray background color. I cannot figure out what that part of the screen is called and any information about this would be very useful. I am currently working on the IOS part first but android tips would be helpful too.[image]

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750781/change-the-color-of-the-top-and-bottom-bar-controlsbar-statusbar-in-a-xamarin ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
this.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(30, 0, 0), 0, 0);
```

[image]