# Xamarin.Forms - Change StatusBar Color with no navigation bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color) shows how to set the status bar color for iOS.  However, I have HasNavigationBar=false on my pages, so how can I set the color for when you aren't using a nav bar?

My page...

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
```

Comment: `NavigationBar` and `StatusBar` are different things. You will have to do it in the platform-specific code. There were no way to do that out of the box until XF 3.5. [This article](https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/08/20/dynamically-changing-the-status-bar-appearance-in-xamarin-forms/) can help you to get a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add code to the FinishedLaunching method of your AppDelegate class within your iOS project. For example to set status bars color to some shade of green

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   // set status bar color to green
   UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
   statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(61, 205, 88);

   // the usual suspects follow
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
   LoadApplication(new App());

   return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For those looking at this now, this now longer works in iOS13 and will crash.

Comment: Have you compiled with the latest version of Xamarin?

Comment: Not the latest. The app is currently on Xamarin.Forms 3.6. I will try to upgrade to the latest XF version and see if am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This AppDelegate code changes the status bar color for both iOS 13 and older iOS versions.

```
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
  {
        int red = 11;
        int green = 22;
        int blue = 33;

        // the usual Xamarin.Forms code
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        bool canLoadUrl = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

        // get status bar and set color
        UIView statusBar;
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            const int tag = 999; 

            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
            if (window is null) return null;

            statusBar = window.ViewWithTag(tag) ?? new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame)
            {
                Tag = tag
            };

            window.AddSubview(statusBar);
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
        }
        if (!(statusBar is null))
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(red, green, blue);
        }

        return canLoadUrl;
   }
```