# get rid of default blue in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms project, I don't know how to get rid of the default blue in the background. I changed the primary color in the resource dictionary in app.xaml. it works well on the individual pages, but they're still some blue in the background (see screen-shots attached) that I need to change too.
thanks heaps in advance

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Primary">BurlyWood</Color>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#332196F3" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oVGY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP4fz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bar. Navigation bar and Status bar.
For the Navigation Bar add this code inside of `ResourceDictionary` tag

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
      <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

Or, Add this two line inside the constructor of your `MainPage.xaml.cs` file

```
BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
BarTextColor = Color.Black;
```

And for the StatusBar follow below link instruction:

Android: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color)

IoS: [Click Here](https://dev.to/dotnet/change-the-ios-status-bar-color-in-xamarin-forms-4hgd)

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, it works like a charm, except I couldn't test for ios, but I'll worry about that later. Thanks again!